# Get today day value from array

Tags: javascript

I have the below list of days. I want to get the value of today's day. For example, if today is Friday, then I should get "11:30 AM – 9:30 PM". How I can do this in JavaScript?

```
["Monday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", "Tuesday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", 
 "Wednesday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", "Thursday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", 
 "Friday: 11:30 AM – 9:30 PM", "Saturday: 11:30 AM – 9:30 PM", 
"Sunday: 11:30 AM – 9:00 PM"]

let a = currentTime.split(':');
if(a[2]>1){
  a[1]=parseInt(a[1])+1
}
let hours = a[0]
let minutes = a[1]
```

Also, how I can check if time like 15:02:01pm exist between time 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM or 15:02:01pm between 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM?

Comment: Forget the language for a minute. What you have there is a list of strings in a specific format. Think about how you would parse a list of strings with a fixed format for a specific value. After you have your algorithm, then you can think about how to implement it in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the current weekday from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday):

```
const today = new Date().getDay();
```

Adjust it to match the array, where 0 is Monday:

```
const today = (new Date().getDay() + 6) % 7;
```

Remove the name of the day from the corresponding entry:

```
const values = ["Monday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", …];
const value = values[today].split(': ')[1];
```

It might help at this point to wrap your input time parsing into a function that returns the number of minutes since 0:00:

```
const parseInputTime = time => {
    const [hours, minutes] = time.split(':').map(Number);

    return 60 * hours + minutes;
};
```

Parsing a given time in a range is similar:

```
const parseRangeTime = time => {
    const parts = time.split(/[: ]/);
    const hours = parseInt(parts[0], 10) + (parts[2] === 'PM' ? 12 : 0);
    const minutes = parseInt(parts[1], 10);

    return 60 * hours + minutes;
};
```

Then you can use these functions and compare the results:

```
const [start, end] = value.split(' – ');
const isInRange =
    parseInputTime(currentTime) >= parseRangeTime(start) &&
    parseInputTime(currentTime) < parseRangeTime(end);
```

[**full demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fb19nys5/)

Comment: Also, how I can check if 15:02:01pm exist between time like 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM or 15:02:01pm between 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM?

Comment: @shanky: You would have to parse the numbers out of the string – with a regex, for example. Where are you getting the input? Is the same information maybe available in a more convenient format?

Comment: I'm getting the time input from input box like (22:57:58) and I'm splitting the time values const checkVals = checkVal.replace(/\s/g, '').split('–');. Then I'm trying to check if input=(22:57:58) is exisiting between checkVals[0] and checkVals[1]. But still I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: @shanky: So for the input time `22:57:58`, you’d want to split it into hours, minutes, and seconds, then add one to the minutes if the seconds aren’t zero, resulting in `hours = 22`, `minutes = 58`. Then for each part in the range, you could use `/(\d+):(\d+) (AM|PM)/.exec(time)` to get the hours and minutes there and compare the two. If you still need help, just edit what you have into the question and I’ll update the answer accordingly. =)

Comment: I still can't figure it out. I've updated the question.

Comment: @shanky: Did you come up with something for the first step, i.e. parsing `22`, `57`, and `58` out of `22:27:58` and rounding to the next minute?

Comment: I'll do it now.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, I've updated the question with parsing of time.

Comment: @shanky: Updated the answer. It’s a bit messy, but that’s just the nature of text parsing sometimes.

Comment: but it gives false value even though current time (const currentTime = '22:57:58';) between "Saturday: 4:30 PM –  11:42 PM",?

Comment: @shanky: In /1, there are multiple spaces; if you need to support that, use `value.split(/\s*–\s*/)`.

Comment: If end time is 2:00 AM then above case produces false value, which is incorrect.

Comment: @shanky: Add `60 * 24` if the end time is before the start time, but how are you going to distinguish 1 AM on Saturday (out of range) from 1 AM on Sunday (in range)?

Answer (score 1):

This also works.

```js
const days = ["Monday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", "Tuesday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", 
 "Wednesday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", "Thursday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", 
 "Friday: 11:30 AM – 9:30 PM", "Saturday: 11:30 AM – 9:30 PM", 
"Sunday: 11:30 AM – 9:00 PM"]

let today = new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'long' })

let todaysTime = '';

for (let i=0; i < days.length; i++) {
  if (days[i].indexOf(today) !== -1 ) {
    todaysTime = days[i].substr(today.length + 2)
  }
}

console.log(todaysTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var x = ["Monday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", "Tuesday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", 
 "Wednesday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", "Thursday: 11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM", 
 "Friday: 11:30 AM – 9:30 PM", "Saturday: 11:30 AM – 9:30 PM", 
"Sunday: 11:30 AM – 9:00 PM"];

for(var i =0;i< x.length;i++){console.log(x[i].substring(0,x[i].indexOf(':')));}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I changed the way the data is stored

```js
var array  =  [
            {name: "Monday", value :"11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM"}, 
            {name: "Tuesday", value :"11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM"}, 
            {name: "Wednesday", value :"11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM"}, 
            {name: "Thursday",  value :"11:30 AM – 2:30 PM, 5:30 – 10:30 PM"}, 
            {name: "Friday  ", value : "11:30 AM – 9:30 PM"}, 
            {name: "Saturday", value : "11:30 AM – 9:30 PM"}, 
            {name: "Sunday  ", value : "11:30 AM – 9:00 PM"}
           ];  
             
           function myFunction() {
             var obj = array.filter(function ( obj ) {
              return obj.name === 'Wednesday';
             })[0];
        
             window.alert(obj.value);  
           }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```